# How to call take picture method in IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera

My friends, I googled a lot but find nothing. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821 and my objective is put a new button to take picture. But I have no idea to call take picture camera method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) class which is what lets you access the camera functions of your iOS device.

Specifically, you'll want to use the source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` (first checking if the device has a camera via `isSourceTypeAvailable:`), with media type `kUTTypeImage`,  present the camera controller via `presentViewController`, and you can then either display the default camera controls, or hide them and take a picture by firing off the `takePicture` method when the user presses the custom button.

Comment: Thanks, my friend, sorry for don't look in the principal place. I only needed call [self takePicture].

Comment: taking advantage of this thread, I need to hide toolBar, I tried this example, but nothing happens http://pastebin.com/BQHdMCq2

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is going to be to use the UIImagePickerController class. You can present this view controller modally, and you will get a delegate callback with the picture that was taken.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
     [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
else // The device doesn't have a camera, so use something like the photos album
     [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];

[self presentViewControler:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The delegate method to use is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

If you need to take a picture without using UIImagePickerController, say if you want your own custom interface, you'll need to dive into AVFoundation, which is an advanced topic that you are probably not ready for.